# ffmpeg - mandatory filters to use

Tags: android, filter, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I am compiling ffmpeg for android. Just wondering which filters are mandatory in the configuration. If anybody knows please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of the stackoverflow questions the answer is extracted as below.

> Filters are only significant if you
>   plan on using them. Have a look at
>   what the filters do and then decide
>   for yourself.
>
> If all you do is just watch videos
>   with ffplay then it's likely you won't
>   need them. If you use ffmpeg for
>   things like analog to digital
>   conversion, re-encoding of videos then
>   it's likely you will need them.